# Unity UI Ball image bounce left/right with parent rect image

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a meter of sorts where there is a ball image that is a child to a rect image and I want it to bounce back and forth. This is all unity UI stuff. The width of the parent rect could be anything and it should adapt.

[image]

The idea is the ball bounces back and forth and if the ball is fully inside the red area when you click it's a success and an event is fired.

ChatGPT gave the following code but it doesn't work. The ball goes outside the bounds.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class BallMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed = 5f;
private RectTransform parentRect;

int direction = 1;

void Start()
{
    // Get the parent rectangle's RectTransform
    parentRect = transform.parent.GetComponent<RectTransform>();

    // Ensure the parentRect is not null
    if (parentRect == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Parent rectangle's RectTransform not found!");
    }
}

void Update()
{
    // Calculate the movement limits based on the aspect ratio and parent position
    float aspectRatio = Screen.width / (float)Screen.height;
    float canvasWidth = parentRect.rect.width * aspectRatio;
    float leftLimit = parentRect.position.x - canvasWidth / 2f;
    float rightLimit = parentRect.position.x + canvasWidth / 2f;

    // Move the ball automatically left and right within the calculated limits
    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    // Change direction when reaching the limits
    if (transform.position.x < leftLimit || transform.position.x > rightLimit)
    {
        direction *= -1;
    }
}
```

}

[EDIT] Actually is there a way to do this with animations? That way I can have finer control over the ball.

Comment: Yeah GPT is all wrong on this one (not unusual). You want to use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localPosition.html, this will give you a position relative to the parent, so you can then use width of the parent rect to calculate the bounds e.g. if it's 100 wide with anchors in the centre then the your range is -50 to 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really need to go through `Screen` nor `aspectRatio` ... you only care about the width of the parent rect and the width of the ball rect ... from these two you can already calculate anything you need:

```
public class BallMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f;

    private RectTransform parentRect;
    private RectTransform ownRect;
    
    private int direction = 1;
    
    void Start()
    {
        // Get the parent rectangle's RectTransform
        if(!transform.parent.TryGetComponent<RectTransform>(out parentRect))
        {
            Debug.LogError("Parent rectangle's RectTransform not found!");
        }

        if(!TryGetComponent<RectTransform>(out ownRect))
        {
            Debug.LogError("Own RectTransform not found!");
        }
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        var parentWidth = parentRect.rect.width;
        var ownWidth = ownRect.rect.width;
        var maxOffset = (parentWidth - ownWidth) / 2f;

        var position = ownRect.anchoredPosition;
        position.x = Mathf.Clamp(position.x + direction * speed * Time.deltaTime, -maxOffset, maxOffset);
        ownRect.anchoredPosition = position;

        if(Mathf.Approximately(Mathf.Abs(position.x), maxOffset))
        {
            direction *= -1;
        }
    }
}
```

All that's left is to ensure that your ball object is anchored to the **center** of the parent in the Inspector:

```
Anchors
    Min      X 0.5  Y 0.5
    Max      X 0.5  Y 0.5
Pivot        X 0.5  Y 0.5
```